# Can't add Gmail after setting up Google app @domain address

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I set up Google Apps @domain.ie and wanted to add Gmail to setup email addresses. It looked a straightforward process to do once you do all this in the one session. However, I just registered the domain and then logged out to come back and add the various email addresses on Gmail later.

When I went to go back in I received the error message:

> Gmail has not been enabled by the administrator of the domain @festivals.ie. You can sign into another account to use Gmail.
>
> If you are the Google Apps administrator, please read these articles to learn more about controlling user access to Google Apps services and turning services on/off for certain users.

and having looked at various videos in Google help, I still can't see how to get the task completed. I can't delete the email and start again either. So I just need some guidance at this stage.

Comment: Did you verify your site? :) You will need to put a file to your hosting in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

**From [this Google support article](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182442):**

> To select which services are available to users:
>
> 1. Log in to the Google Apps administrator control panel.
> 2. Click the Organization & users tab.
> 3. Click the Services tab.
> 4. For each Google Apps service, the Services tab shows whether the service is currently ON or OFF for users in the selected
>      organizational unit.
> 5. Click Save changes.

Its also possible that you havent [**verified your domain ownership**](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60216)  and/or **[setup your MX records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352)**.

Comment: Your answer worked for me. After setting up the MX records on my domain registrar's panel I couldn't access my very first email account (the webmaster's), so I turned off Gmail for everyone and immediately turned it on again. Everything works fine now. Oh! And I am using the new Google Apps Admin Console.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, try this: Go to the cpanel for your domain, click on Organization & users in the nav bar and then the Services submenu, finally you need to toggle Gmail OFF, then ON again, then save the changes. Try logging in again.

If this doesn't work try resetting the password, then clear your browser cache.